# Interpretation of interaction coefficients in difference-in-difference

Tags: regression, interaction, econometrics, interpretation, difference-in-difference

There are two time periods: 2010 and 2015

There are two groups: treatment and control group

The equation looks like this:

$$
y= a + b_1\text{treat}+ b_2\text{post} + b_3\text{treat}\cdot\text{post} + u
$$

where treat is a dummy variable: 1 for treatment group, 0 for control group

post is a dummy: 1 for 2015 and  for 2010.

The y variable is also dummy: job or no job. Having a job is coded as 1, no job is coded as 0

What is the interpretation of the post variable?

Suppose the value of coefficient of post variable is 0.20. Then, can we say that the probability of having a job if you are in the control group in 2015 is higher by 0.20. But my doubt is what should be our baseline comparison for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Baseline is control group in 2010: Y=a.

Comment: got it! thanks!